# Java Generics clarification

Tags: java, generics

There I though I understood Java generics until I tried to write the following:

```
class A{}

class B{
    A a;

    <T extends A> T getA(){ 
       return a; // does not compile
    }
}
```

I get a compilation error saying the types are incompatible: required T, found A.

1. Why am I getting the error?
2. I would be happy to get a reference to an article that describes this kind of java generics pitfalls.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it compiled, it wouldn't be type-safe:

```
B b = new B();
b.a = new A();

SubclassOfA foo = b.<SubclassOfA>getA();
```

The compiler can't guarantee that `a` will be an instance of `T`, and it can't even check it at execution-time due to type erasure - so it won't compile.

In general the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) covers just about everything.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that should work:

```
class B<T extends A>{
    T a;

    T getA(){ 
       return a;
    }
}
```

Client code can be sure that getA() returns a sub-type of A, just as above, but the compiler can also be sure that it's the right sub-type of A

Answer (score -3):

`T extends A` means `T` must be subsclass of `A` and not `A` itself. In your case you want something like:

```
<T> T getA() {
    return a;
}
```

Here is [tutorial on java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).

Comment: "T extends A means T must be subsclass of A and not A itself". This is not true. In Generics, both the extends and the super keyword match the Bound itself also.